# Broken iPhone dock connector pins, is this a hazard?

Tags: hardware, iphone, lightning

The dock connector on my iPhone 4S had some bent pins, which I scrubbed  using a jewelry screwdriver until the pins broke and fell out. The phone still charges, and aside from thinking it's always connected to a dock, the phone seems to work fine. However, I am worried about a hazard of some type, for example is there any risk of shock or fire or something else?

Image shows bent pins, this is before I broke them off with the screwdriver.

[image: iPhone with bent pins]

Comment: If you broke them off cleanly, it should be fine. The issue comes if you create a short between two or more of them.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the phone appears to be still working fine I would advice to get the device looked over and possibly repaired.

The main problem is without seeing which pins have broken off, the device maybe missing earth pins which could cause a risk of electrical shock, I would be very cautious when charging the device.

[image: iPhone 4S pinout]

This should not cost to much as the port can be purchased fairly cheap on eBay.

[image: iPhone 4S dock connector]